# Why are 'Anonymous Users' Editing questions that sound like they are the OP?

Tags: discussion

I keep seeing 'Suggested edits' like this appearing where an "Anonymous user" is editing the question and makes it sound like the OP is the one making the edit. 
See below:
[image: Op Anon?]

Is this actually a random anonymous user just tacking on or is it the OP who's just to lazy to log in or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell. Sometimes users, especially new ones who don't necessarily know how the site works, well post without logging back in.

Other times it seems like a different user - if so I tend to reject the edit and give a reason.

Comment: Agreed.  In addition, for the particular example you listed, no matter whether it was the original poster or not, that looks like a pretty low-quality edit.  (I know, it doesn't show context, so I probably shouldn't judge without the surrounding context, but... this is not how questions should be edited, in an ideal world.  Ideally, the result of an edit should be a revised question that, if it stood alone, would be a good question.)